# Dolby Vooxet sdk Incoming call Android

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, dolby, dolby-audio-api

I am implement **dolby.io sdk** for Audio,Video call in my application.

Everything working fine but we are not getting incoming call notification when app is closed or killed.
Does any one knows how to trigger incoming call notification to specific user if app is closed or killed using **dolby sdk, vooxet sdk**.

Thanks in advance.